# Text Alignement under specific items

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

I want to align my text under the symbol ":" or another, for example I want something like that :

```
 First thing : Blablablabla ...
               Blablabla
 Second : blablablabla
          blabla
```

And I don't know how to do it, I tried many environments, like {enumerate} or {itemize} or {description} but none of them worked.

How can I do something like I want ?

Thank you.

---

Thank you, but it didn't help me much : in fact I want to write what I want before having the remaing text aligned, for example for the references in an article :

```
[Friedman1967] Here there is the reference
               which is long.
[Zu2014] Here is an other, the alignment is different.
         but it is stil coherent.
```

I do not know if I am very clear sorry.

Comment: There is a similar question already solved [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107384/alignment-of-text-in-itemize-environment). It uses the package [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want is not quite clear. You have a list, and you want lines after the first to be aligned with the colon?

Comment: Yes, you understand well, it is like the examples I gave. So whar do I need to do ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to obtain the desired alignment is to define a custom macro:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\LabelWidth}
\newcommand*{\AlignedText}[2]{%
    \par\noindent\textbf{#1:}
    \settowidth{\LabelWidth}{\textbf{#1} }%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LabelWidth-\parsep\relax}{#2\strut}%
}

\begin{document}
\AlignedText{Friedman1967}{Here is the reference
               which is quite long and spills onto a second line.}
\AlignedText{Zu2014}{Here is an other, the alignment is different,
         but it is still coherent, and also takes more than one line.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I want ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Mickael: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).